# Map host's /etc/hosts in a Docker container having bridge networking

Tags: networking, docker, dns, hosts

I have a host machine with some hosts resolution defined in its /etc/hosts file.

On this machine I'm running my Docker containers configured with a Bridge network.
Since I'm not on the host network my Docker containers have no access of the hosts definitions of my machine /etc/hosts file.

Unfortunately having a DNS it is not an option at the moment.

My question is how can I make use of those definitions in my containers using bridge networking? I read mounting the hosts /etc/hosts file in the container is not a good choice since that's handled internally by the docker deamon.
Do you know how else I can achieve this?

Comment: is this possible ? copy your host /etc/hosts to container /tmp/foo, then append /tmp/foo to container's /etc/hosts

Answer (score 4):

I think it may be better to use the command-line option of `--add-host` to add entries into the `/etc/hosts` of the container.

Here is an excerpt from the [official Docker Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)

> **Managing `/etc/hosts`**
>
> Your container will have lines in /etc/hosts which define the hostname
>   of the container itself as well as localhost and a few other common
>   things. The --add-host flag can be used to add additional lines to
>   /etc/hosts.
>
> ```
> $ docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
> 172.17.0.22     09d03f76bf2c
> fe00::0         ip6-localnet
> ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
> ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
> ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> ::1               localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
> 86.75.30.9      db-static
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options

`docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts <yourimage>`

the problem with the option is, that your container hosts file is overwritten, which will backfire if you want to contact any other service in that docker-network.

Thus i would do

`docker run -v /etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts <yourimage>`

And use a entrypoint in your image, which does something among this lines

`cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts`

a) You want to filter out some lines like localhost, or select specific lines using grep
b) You want to ensure you do not repeat this on every container bootstrap, so write a semaphore or similar ( a file, check the file whatever )